# Is it possible to stretch Plain Text lines vertically to fit div height with CSS only?

Tags: css

I want the Plain Text lines in a div to stretch evenly vertically to fill the div height, without using `line-height` since I don't know how many lines will be there

It can be done with jQuery but is it possible with pure CSS?

Comment: Can you use those "lines" as div background? If the answer is "yes", you could try with `background-repeat:repeat-y` css's property

Comment: @DonCallisto thanx but no, plain text lines

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible.

line-height % would work on font-size, not on outer height.
And you did not even fix the number of lines

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with border, but not sure if this is what you are looking for. 
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EChzQ/

```
<div>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>

div{
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
div span{
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #f00
}
```

Comment: 'I want the lines in a div to stretch evenly vertically to fill the div height' This is what the code above does. Are you looking for something different?